# How to create upright vertical oriented text in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, text-rendering

It is easy to create a Text object in Matplotlib rotated 90 degrees with `rotation='vertical'`, like this [image]

But I want to create Text objects like this [image]

How?

Comment: I don't think there is such method because what you want is a splitted string. This is one way you can do: `text = '2018-08-11'` and then extract individual characters as `chars = [j for i in text.split('-') for j in i]` and then loop over them and use `plt.text` with a fixed `x` and changing `y` value

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`'\n'.join(my_string)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to insert newline characters (`\n`) between each character of the string (`my_string`).

If you also want to strip out the `-` symbols (which is implied in your question), you can use the [`.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) function to remove them.

Consider the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

my_string = '2018-08-11'

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

ax.text(0.1, 0.5, my_string, va='center')
ax.text(0.3, 0.5, my_string, rotation=90, va='center')
ax.text(0.5, 0.5, '\n'.join(my_string), va='center')
ax.text(0.7, 0.5, '\n'.join(my_string.replace('-', '')), va='center')

plt.show()
```

[image]